# ssh welcome message is gone after remove node and angular

Tags: ssh

I have same problem like [ssh welcome message is suddenly gone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1438227/ssh-welcome-message-is-suddenly-gone) but cant comment on it.

I am pretty sure that the problem comes after remove node and angular from the system.

The solution in the first question and reinstall ubuntu is not a valid option to me.

Does anybody know what happens when intalling angular on ubuntu? I have to fix my .bashrc becuase there was a new line for angular autocompletion inside.

Comment: You wouldn't install Angular and Node in Ubuntu. You install Node using NVM your home folder, and install Angular in each project. Does the problem also occur in another user account?

Comment: Is there a `.hushlogin` (hidden file) in your user's home directory?

Comment: There is no .hushlogin file in home directory

Comment: There is only one user in the system. I not able to create a new one just for testing. :-/

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the problem but dont know why this was the problem.
I have found in `/run` the `motd.dynamic.new`file and renamed it to `motd.dynamic`. After that everything was working as before.

Comment: `/run` is reset at reboot. Does it still work?

Comment: Dont reboot the system yet. The system cant get reboot and not reinstalled. Thats the problem :-/